# Unable to parse 02-Mar-00 Date java 5

Tags: java

Unable to parse date 02-Mar-00.

Format is -> dd-MMM-yyyy

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        df.setLenient(false);
        date = df.parse(dateString);
```

The error message -

```
Unparseable date: "02-Mar-00"

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02-Mar-00"
at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:388)
at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:9)
```

Comment: yyyy, 00, something doesn’t add up. Also always add error messages, actual runnable code etc.

Comment: yyyy - 00 are not same check the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, this won't work until you match your request to the format that you want to parse to!

```
    String dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yy";
    String dateString = "02-Mar-00";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    df.setLenient(false);
    try {
        Date date = df.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This parses the input string to the following output!

```
Input: 02-Mar-00

Output: Thu Mar 02 00:00:00 IST 2000
```

Hope this answers your question well!

Comment: But I have string as this 02-Mar-00. Do I have to use a different format to do so?

Comment: Yes, you need to @ash164 !

Comment: Updated my answer @ash164. Can you check and let me know if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

first you have to parse the date as @N00b Pr0grammer posted
and then format it again in the desired format. I have made some modifications to it, just check it out

```
String dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yy";
String dateString = "02-Mar-00";
String newFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
DateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
df.setLenient(false);
try {
    Date date = df.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(displayFormat.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```